# What is \ before name of BaseController in Laravel?

Tags: php, syntax

I am new in Laravel, I am watching a video tutorial about Laravel, He made a controller and named that like below:

```
class AdminAuthController extends \BaseController{
   //Methods and codes goes here
}
```

**What is \ before BaseController?**

Comment: @RakeshSharma oh, I think you are right. he putted this controller in a **admin** directory. Do you mean if I put it in **admin/folder** I should write \\BaseController ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Slash at the start of an object name references it's namespace location.
Basically it being in the Global namespace in this case.

Comment: he putted this controller in a admin directory. Do you mean if I put it in admin/folder I should write \\BaseController ?

Comment: do you have PSR autoloading in your project ?

Comment: What is PSR autoloading ? I am using Laravel Framework

Comment: where is the admin folder located ?

Comment: into controller folder

Answer (score 1):

It extends BaseController, which is declared in the global namespace.

Comment: he putted this controller in a admin directory. Do you mean if I put it in admin/folder I should write \\BaseController ?

Comment: @user4419488 No, this has nothing to do with directories. Namespaces is purely a "virtual" concept, if you will. There is however a common convention that namespaces is derived from the directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks for the BaseController in global namespace

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php